# Did *ngFor usage change?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Before I go into this, the code was working great just awhile back and I haven't made changes, but I am wondering if Angular updated their variable referencing or what.

I have a JSON array that is raw and assigned to an `any`-type variable `siteList`.
When I run `console.log(siteList)` it spits out the JSON object perfectly.

Used to when I ran the code below everything worked and showed up just fine.

```
<div *ngFor="let site of siteList" class="card mat-elevation-z8" style="margin: 20px; border: 1px solid lightgrey;">
  <div class="card-header" style="background: #f88d3d; color: white;">
    {{site.Name}} &nbsp; - &nbsp; {{site.Age | date}}
    <span *ngIf="site.Location != null">
      &nbsp; - &nbsp;
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    </span>
    <mat-radio-button (click)="setSite(site.SiteId)" class="float-right"></mat-radio-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The strange thing is, it's making the appropriate amount of cards so it is taking in the object correctly. But none of my variable references are working like they used to. Is it because `siteList` is defined as `any` and not like a full class? I am just floored because I have not changed anything.

Comment: What exactly is not working like before? Do you have any errors? Are you sure that `siteList` structure didn't change (if it's from api or from anywhere out of the app)?

Comment: Oh sorry I should have been more specific. So site.Name and site.Age are not showing up in the div at all. They used to show on the screen. The json structure I get back is fine.

Comment: And you don't get any errors and `siteList` is having `Name` and `Age` properties? Are you getting the `siteList` from async subscription?

Comment: Can you post the siteList? (And no, *ngFor did not change)

Comment: You need to share the json structure too. The issue may be in the json. If possible create a small stackblitz of the issue

Comment: Ah I just found out that angular is deprecated and that google doesn't support it anymore so that is probably why my things arnt working.

Comment: Huh? Angular deprecated? Angular is certainly very much active and alive...

Comment: @Casey Angular is the most well structured front end framework ever and is still evolving. And yes, AngularJS is deprecated. Also *ngFor usage did not change. Ifyour question is not answered can you please provide a minimal reproducible example and (if present) the error logs? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example